# Remix IDE: Parse error : expected '{' but got 'return'

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, error, ide

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;

    uint public totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** 10;
    string public name = "RUSHIT";
    string public symbol = "REA";
    uint public decimals = 10;

   event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, unit value);
   event approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
   
    constructor(){
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function balancesOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balancesOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public return(bool) {
        require(balances(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

With the following error :
`30 | function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public return(bool) { | ^^^^`

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in function definition it should be `returns` instead of `return`.

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool)
```